# Plugin: database creation

Tags: plugin-development, database, customization

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this function?

```
function xattachments_db_install() {
   global $wpdb;
   $xattachments_db_version = "1.0";
   $table_name = $wpdb->prefix ."xattachments";

   $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$table_name. " (
        'xattachments_id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
        'xattachments_name'  varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
        'xattachments_title' varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
        'post_id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
        'xattachments_data_id' int(11) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY ('xattachments_id') 
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin ;";

   require_once(ABSPATH.'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
   dbDelta($sql);
   add_option("xattachments_db_version", $xattachments_db_version);     
}
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'xattachments_db_install');
```

It doesn't generate any error message when I activate the plugin but the table is not created in the database.

This function is located at the very beginning of the plugin file.

Thank you.

Comment: Code is OK as first look. Its should work. try to debug what sql running in dbDelta.

Comment: thank you Code Monkey. How would I do that?

Comment: Find location of dbDelta,  check what arguments it gets, test that arguments (its sql which should run).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part in your table creation SQL looks wrong: `DEFAULT CHARSET=CHARSET=utf8`. It should just be `DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`.

Also, [`dbDelta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins#Creating_or_Updating_the_Table) is quite a delicate function. Don't ask me why, but you need to put a *double* space after the `PRIMARY KEY` keyword. You also need to get rid of the quotes around the field names because `dbDelta()` chokes on those. Don't use backticks neither.

And, of course, set `WP_DEBUG` to `TRUE` while debugging.